# Remote debugging production IIS on Azure virtual machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I have a web site on an Azure virtual machine which I need to debug in production since it is working fine on my development machine.

I have installed the remote debugger tools on the server, I have allowed the .exe through the firewall, and I have added endpoints for the ports 4016,4017 for the machine in the Azure portal administration site.

When I try to attach to the process I enter my servers address *.cloudapp.net but it does not connect. I have tried without authentication and with windows authentication, I have also created duplicate local windows accounts on both machines with the same passwords.

Also I have checked that the local security policy is set up so that users may authenticate as themselves.

All in all, I seem to have done everything correct but still no success.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, 
Peter Larsson!

Comment: I've found this blog article, if it helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx/ - Remote Debugging a Window Azure Web Site with Visual Studio 2013. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is now supported. Read here for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx),

> Debugging over the internet is not supported.

Instead [you are advised to use IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683671.aspx) to run your app and then follow execution from the IntelliTrace log. Note that this requires Visual Studio Ultimate.

The other alternative that I am aware of is to set up a VPN to allow you to attach the debugger in the normal fashion.